# How to build a dynamically growing nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Assuming there is the following code which checks if the multiplied digits of a number equal an input number:

```
results = [a for a in range(10) if a == input]
results += [a*b for a in range(10) for b in range(10) if a*b == input]
results += [a*b*c for a in range(10) for b in range(10) for c in range(10) if a*b*c == input]
...
```

I want it to change so that it dynamically continues to search for a match if no result was found yet. So:

- If one-digit numbers don't yield a result, continue with two-digit numbers
- If two-digit numbers don't yield a result, continue with three-digit numbers
- and so on ...

I'd like to do that in an elegant way, even a one-liner if that's not too involute. I also would need a break condition to avoid infinite loops if there is no match at all. For example if the input is a prime number > 10 there is no result. The break condition should be something like:

```
if(math.pow(2, countOfDigits) > input):
    return
```

where `countOfDigits` is the number of digits that are currently checked in the nested list comprehension. In other words, the first line of my initial example represents `countOfDigits == 1`, the second line `countOfDigits == 2` and the third line `countOfDigits == 3`.

Comment: Your code and your text disagree. Your're talking about multiplying digits, but your code adds them. Also, do you want the first result only, or all results for n-digits numbers (for the first n that yields any results)?

Comment: What do you mean by "no match at all"? What's the stopping condition? (From the way you've phrased your question, it looks like it continues indefinitely.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i edited my post to make thing a bit clearer

Comment: I don't understand your definition of the `countOfDigits` at the end.

Comment: What makes you say there's no match if the input is prime? `1 * 7 == 7`

Comment: As your list `results` will only contain the original input repeated some times, the only interesting part of `results` is its length. Are you trying to find the number of true divisors or what is the goal of this?

Comment: Are you trying to find all the factors of a number?

Comment: I too am curious on what the goal of this is

Comment: martineau: i added an explanation -
SteveJessop: prime numbers greather with at least two digits -
the example is simplified. i am doing something else in the loop body and at the end i am taking the minimum value or return zero if there is no match.

Comment: Trying to understand your question: The expected result for `input == 7` is `[7, 7, 7]` as `7 == 7 == 1 * 7 == 7 * 1` and `2**3 > 7`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes Hyperboerus. My attempt to simplify the question to direct the focus to the nested loops was not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a list comprehension. I think a generator would be better here:

```
def generate(x):
    for digits in itertools.count(1):
        for i in itertools.product(range(1, 10), repeat=digits):
            if reduce(operator.mul, i) == x:
                yield i
    if (math.pow(2, digits) > x):
        break
```

Then you do `for i in generate(input_number)`.

(You also need `import itertools`, `from functools import reduce` and `import math` at the top).

((math.pow(2, digits) > x) is just the break condition.)

Comment: out of curiosity: is it possible to convert this to a one-liner?

Comment: @Alp Yes (see Steve Jessop's answer, which is basically this in a different format). But I don't think you want to, IMHO something like this is much more readable.

Answer (score 7):

Oh, go on then:

```
next(
    sum(x) 
    for i in range(1, input) # overkill
    for x in itertools.product(range(10), repeat = i) 
    if reduce(operator.mul, x) == input
)
```

Edit: you've changed the question to return the product rather than the sum, so spit out `input` instead of `sum(x)`.

I'm not immediately sure whether you want the first match, or you want all matches where the number of factors is equal to the smallest possible. If the latter, you can do it by spitting `input, i` out of this iterator, then use `itertools.groupby` to collect them according to the second value in the tuple, then take only the first value in the result of that, and iterate over it to get all matches (although, since you're now outputting `input` that's kind of uninteresting other than maybe for its length).

Comment: @sweeneyrod Why not? Looks legit.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I think he means that he (quite sensibly) doesn't write code like this ;-)

Comment: @Hyperboreus I just meant the way it's written, as a multiline generator expression insid the function makes it look like some weird version of Python without assignments or loop bodies.

Comment: neat! `itertools.product` is exactly what i needed. i may have asked a better question to get this insight

Comment: the break condition is indeed overkill. is there a way to break out of the whole nested loop if a condition is met?

Comment: @Alp - either `raise` a custom exception, put the loop in a function and return, or refactor.

Comment: @Alp: just change the upper limit of the first range to `int(math.ceil(math.log(input+1,2)))` or whatever. I was too lazy to work out the tight bound, and the first version of your question just asked for *a* limit, not necessarily a *good* limit :-)

Comment: And I guess there's no point starting at 1 when you could start at something like `int(math.floor(math.log(input, 9)))`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: "some weird version of Python without assignments or loop bodies" -- welcome to "writing in a functional style in imperative languages ... for fun and profit!" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

What you want is a thing which can be iterated over, but which does no work until as late as possible.  That's not a list, and so a list comprehension is the wrong tool.  Fortunately, you can use a *generator expression*.  Your code is quite elaborate, so we'll want to probably use some helpers defined in the standard library, in `itertools`.

lets start by looking at the general case of your parts:

```
[n

   for x0 in range(10) 
   for x1 in range(10)
   ...
   for xn in range(10) 

 if x0 * x1 * ... * xn == input]
```

We have three parts to generalize.  We'll start with the nested for loops, as arguments of N.  for this we'll use `itertools.product`, It takes a sequence of sequences, something like `[range(10), range(10), ... , range(10)]` and produces every possible combination of items out of those sequences.  In the special case of looping over a sequence multiple times, you can just pass the depth of nesting as `repeat`, so we can get to:

```
[n

   for x in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=n)

 if x[0] * x[1] * ... * x[n] == input]
```

For the sum in the output, we can flatten it to a single value with `sum()`, for the product, there's not really an equivalent.  We can make one out of `reduce` and a function that multiplies two numbers together, which we can get from another standard library: `operator.mul`:

```
(n
 for x in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=n)
 if reduce(operator.mul, x, 1) == input)
```

So far so good, now we just need to repeat this inner part for every value of n.  Supposing we want to search forever, we can get an unending sequence of numbers with `itertools.count(1)`, and Finally, we just need to turn this flatten sequence of sequences into a single sequence, for which we can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(
     (n
      for x in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=n)
      if reduce(operator.mul, x, 1) == input)
     for n in itertools.count(1)
     if 2 ** n > input))
```

```
In [32]: input = 32

In [33]: next(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (n
         for x in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=n)
         if reduce(operator.mul, x, 1) == input)
        for n in itertools.count(1) if 2 ** n > input))
Out[33]: 6
```

Comment: OP changed his question and now he is populating his list only with `input` itself. Please check to see the question again.

Comment: great explanation. no need to check my question again, this is very helpful

Comment: there is still a problem: if you set `input` to `31`, `next` tries to find a result in an infinite loop because there is none

Comment: when should I give up?

Comment: still trying to figure out a good break condition, `2 ** n > input` was intended to be a first try

Comment: hmm... maybe you intend for `for n in count(1) if 2**n > input`  should really just be `for n in xrange(1, 2**n+1)`?

Comment: @deque starmap partial setattr You don't need those extra parentheses in the `chain` function, you can do stuff like `function(i for i in iterable)`. Generator expressions are like tuples, you only need the parentheses sometimes.

Comment: @sweeneyrod:  that's true.  I made many edits to this answer, trying to keep up with the question.  I'm glad if that's all that's wrong with it

Comment: Two people have used `chain_from_iterable`. Would you mind reviewing my answer: have I actually made a mistake, or is it just that people avoid comprehensions with multiple `for` clauses for style reasons? I'd certainly allow that they can be a bit ... incomprehensible :-)

Comment: @Steve: I think i can come up with an answer to that question.  Alas, that's a question and this would be an answer, but you've elected to frame it in a comment!

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: but if I asked it as a question it would probably be closed instantly as either "belongs on code review" or "opinionated"! Assuming my code is correct, I am in point of fact asking for your opinion :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have several sequences, each of which may or may not contain the solution. Convert them to generators, use `itertools` to "chain" the sequences together, and then ask for the first element of the resulting sequence (notice that a sequence that does not contain the solution will be empty).

First of all, you need a way to generate sequences of `n`-tuples for any `n`. The `itertools` module has several functions that have effect comparable to nested for-loops. The one that matches your algorithm is `itertools.product`. The following generates all tuples of `n` digits:

```
tuples = itertools.product(range(10), repeat=n)
```

It's actually better to use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, because there's no point testing both `(4,5)` and `(5,4)`. It has similar syntax. So here's a generator that will give you an infinite sequence of n-tuples, for increasing `n`:

```
sequences = ( itertools.product(range(10), repeat=n) for n in itertools.count(1) )
```

Next, you want to string the sequences together (without actually traversing them yet), into a single sequence. Because these are generators, they will only be evaluated if needed.

```
bigchain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sequences)
```

`bigchain` will spit out all tuples you need to check. To test them, you need a way to multiply a tuple of arbitrary length. Let's define it:

```
def mytest(x):
    return reduce(operator.mul, x, 1) == target
```

You can now use this test to "filter" this sequence to select only tuples that match (there will always be many, since you include digit `1` in your combinations), then ask for the first one.

```
print itertools.islice(ifilter(mytest, bigchain), 1).next()
```

I've changed your code to return your solution as a tuple, because otherwise, well, you'll just get back the number you were searching for (e.g., `32`)-- which doesn't tell you anything you didn't know!

Here it is, all together:

```
from itertools import *
import operator

target = 32

sequences = ( combinations_with_replacement(range(10), n) for n in count(1) )
bigchain = chain.from_iterable(sequences)

def mytest(x):
    return reduce(operator.mul, x, 1) == target

print islice(ifilter(mytest, bigchain), 1).next()
# prints (4, 8)
```

You could also eliminate the intermediate variables in the above and combine everything into one expression; but what would be the point?

Comment: thanks, but the most important part is missing: the dynamic generation of more sequences if needed. already figured it out thanks to the other answers